# Prove that for semidefinite operators $v^*Av = 0 \Rightarrow Av=0$ without the Spectral Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

I was just thinking about this fact. It's pretty straightforward to see if we invoke the spectral theorem. But I was curious if someone knew a way to do it way to do it without the spectral theorem.

I also considered using the fact that $A$ has a square root. That is $A = R^*R$ for some matrix $R$ but the only way I know how to prove this fact invokes the spectral theorem so that doesn't really count. So I guess another way to prove this that doesn't use the spectral theorem would also answer my question.